# Parametrization admitting conservation of K & H

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Which mappings admit conservation of K *and* H ? ( Gauss and mean curvatures).

Apart from helicoid/catenoid isometry, which examples can be given of surface bending and distortion so that mean curvature is also invariant during an isometry mapping ?